# php chat notifications - how to autoplay a sound After receiving a new message

Tags: php, include

I want to make an audio file start automatically after receiving a new message.
It works now but does not stop. I want it to work only when receiving any new messages.

```
<?php
include_once("header.php");
$path = "";
$TID = $_POST["TID"];
$x_res = "SELECT * FROM chat WHERE t_id='$UID' AND f_id='$TID' AND t_id_show='0' ";
$f_sql = mysqli_query($CONFIG, $x_res);
$fetch_chat = mysqli_num_rows($f_sql);
if($fetch_chat > 0){
    if($fetch_chat +1){
        echo '<iframe src="style/SD.mp3" allow="autoplay" style="display:none" ></iframe>';
    }
    echo '<q dir="ltr" style="color:red;" > '.$fetch_chat.' </q>';
}
?>
```

This is the code I want to edit to play only when I receive any new messages.

```
<?php
if($fetch_chat +1){
    echo '<iframe src="style/SD.mp3" allow="autoplay" style="display:none" ></iframe>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Set an else statement { echo'<iframe src="style/SD.mp3" allow="" style="display:none" ></iframe>'; } dont play it or return null.

Comment: the proplem in `if($fetch_chat +1)`

Comment: add + 1 on variable $fetch_chat = mysqli_num_rows($f_sql) + 1; before Conditional execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if($fetch_chat +1){
    echo '<iframe src="style/SD.mp3" allow="autoplay" style="display:none" ></iframe>';
}
?>
```